Can Quantum computing really affect Bitcon network?
I was watching a video which mentioned that bitcoin uses a prime number which is 10^77 and a computer doing a trillion computations every trillionth of a second for a trillion years would be less than 10^56. Also there are 10^80 atoms in the universe approx was another claim. Now please let me understand what does that mean and how will quantum computing will not be able to easily affect the security of bitcoin chain?
